# What is n, in this product involving the floor function and lcm

Tags: number-theory, factorial, gcd-and-lcm, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[image: The question involving the floor function, lcm and factorial]

> Let $$P=\prod_{k=1}^{2019} \operatorname{lcm}\left(1,2,\dots,\left\lfloor\frac{2019}k\right\rfloor\right).$$ Given that $P=n!$, find $n$.

This is the question provided, I do not really know how to approach this.

Comment: Related: [Prove that $n!=\prod_{k=1}^n \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,...,\lfloor n/k \rfloor)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3346132). I found that post [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B2019%7D%20%5Coperatorname%7Blcm%7D%5Cleft(1%2C2%2C%5Cdots%2C%5Cleft%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7B2019%7Dk%5Cright%5Crfloor%5Cright)%24&p=1). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: I have retyped the text from the picture. (So you can omit the picture if you're satisfied with the result.) For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).